# How would I set a Jquery variable based on the location and a list of li elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, location

I’m using JQuery 1.11.  I have the following HTML …

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href=“/my_object/index”>My Objects</a></li>
  <li><a href="/my_object/search">Lookup Results</a></li>
    …
  <li><a href="/my_object/edit”>Edit Stuff</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How would I set a variable, “activeIndex” that would be the index of the anchor tag if its href attributes matches the current location?  So for example, if the current location is “https://mydomein.com/my_object/search”, the activeIndex variable would be “1”.

Comment: Where's your js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use window.location.pathname:

```
function activeIndex() {
    var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("nav");
    var listItems = ul[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        var a = listItems[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
        if (a[0].getAttribute("href") === window.location.pathname)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `index` method to determine the index of an element within a array of jquery elements.

```
var activeIndex;
$('ul.nav li a').each(function()
{
  if($(this).attr('href') == window.location.pathname)
     activeIndex = $('ul.nav li a').index(this);
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/jmLynLsg/4/